Relationship between the imagery of Messiah in Targum Jerusalem Exodus 12:42 and Pirkei De Rabbi Eliezer 30:13
In Targum Jerusalem Exodus 12:42 the Messiah is depicted as coming from midst of Rome. And Pirkei De Rabbi Eliezer 30:13 portrays Messiah as coming from Edom (Isaiah 63:1). Was the imagery of Messiah in Targum Jerusalem Exodus 12:42 influenced by Pirikei De Rabbi Eliezer 30:13? Or could it be that the imagery of Messiah in Targum Jerusalem 12:42 is in connection with Babylonian Talmud Sanhedrin 98a:16, Messiah sitting at the gate of Rome?
Targum Jerusalem Exodus 12:42:

It is a night to be observed and celebrated for the liberation from before the Lord in bringing forth the sons of Israel, made free from the land of Mizraim. Four nights are there written in the Book of Memorial. Night first; when the Word of the Lord was revealed upon the world as it was created; when the world was without form and void, and darkness was spread upon the face of the deep, and the Word of the Lord illuminated and made it light; and he called it the first night. Night second; when the Word of the Lord was revealed unto Abraham between the divided parts; when Abraham was a son of a hundred years, and Sarah was a daughter of ninety years, and that which the Scripture saith was confirmed,--Abraham a hundred years, can he beget? and Sarah, ninety year old, can she bear? Was not our father Izhak a son of thirty and seven years, at the time he was offered upon the altar? The heavens were (then) bowed down and brought low, and Izhak saw their realities, and his eyes were blinded at the sight, and he called it the second night. The third night; when the Word of the Lord was revealed upon the Mizraee, at the dividing of the night; His right hand slew the firstborn of the Mizraee, His right hand spared the firstborn of Israel; to fulfil what the Scripture hath said, Israel is My firstborn son. And he called it the third night. Night the fourth; when the end of the age will be accomplished, that it might be dissolved, the bands of wickedness destroyed and the iron yoke broken. Mosheh came forth from the midst of the desert; but the King Meshiha (comes) from the midst of Roma. The Cloud preceded that, and the Cloud will go before this one; and the Word of the Lord will lead between both, and they shall proceed together. This is the night of the Pascha before the Lord, to be observed and celebrated by the sons of Israel in all their generations.

Pirke De Rabbi Eliezer 30:13:

Rabbi Ishmael also said: Three wars of trouble will the sons of Ishmael in the future wage on the earth in the latter days, as it is said, "For they fled away from the swords" (Isa. 21:15). "Swords" signify only wars, one in the forest of Arabia, as it is said, "From the drawn sword" (ibid.); another on the sea, as it is said, "From the bent bow" (ibid.); and one in the great city which is in Rome, which will be more grievous than the other two, as it is said, "And from the grievousness of the war" (ibid.). From there the Son of David shall flourish and see the destruction of these and these, and thence will He come to the land of Israel, as it is said, "Who is this that cometh from Edom, with crimsoned garments from Bozrah? this that is glorious in his apparel, marching in the greatness of his strength? I that speak in righteousness, mighty to save" (ibid. lxiii. 1).

Babylonian Talmud Sanhedrin 98a:16:

Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said to Elijah: When will the Messiah come? Elijah said to him: Go ask him. Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi asked: And where is he sitting? Elijah said to him: At the entrance of the city of Rome. Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi asked him: And what is his identifying sign by means of which I can recognize him? Elijah answered: He sits among the poor who suffer from illnesses. And all of them untie their bandages and tie them all at once, but the Messiah unties one bandage and ties one at a time. He says: Perhaps I will be needed to serve to bring about the redemption. Therefore, I will never tie more than one bandage, so that I will not be delayed.

